# Problem with changing order of elements in html/css

Tags: html, css

I have two elements as parent and child and I want to make the child element to go behind the parent element. I try to add z-index:-1 to child element but nothing happens ... can someone guide me on how to make the child go behind parent element.

```css
.parent {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: coral;
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 200px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: silver;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  parent
  <div class="child">child</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You cannot do it, as parent is the base.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that when you set a `transform` property other than `none`, you define a new stacking context in CSS.  Removing this property fixes the issue. [1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context).

```css
    .parent {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: coral;
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 200px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
/*  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
*/  
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: silver;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">parent
    <div class="child">child</div>
  <div>
```

Answer (score 1):

At this moment, you can't do this. But what you can do is, give the styles of parent to the `::before` pseudo element and you can get it done:

```css
.parent {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 200px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-indent: -99em;
}

.parent::before {
  content: 'parent';
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: coral;
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 200px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: -1;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: silver;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  parent
  <div class="child">child</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that, because the child is wrapped in the parent.
You can only swap parents with parents, and childs with childs. But **but not parents with childs**!

I would recommend to do stuff like this, like swaping parents with parents, via flex-box order.

Idk if it's allowed to share links but this tutorials here are pretty good and helped me a lot. I'm also a beginner

https://youtu.be/JJSoEo8JSnc
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

## edit Okay you can do that, look at the other answer. But for me it's not a clean way to swap parents with childs. I'd avoid to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Put the parent text in a `div` also

```css
.parent {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 200px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.parent-text {
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: coral;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 1px;
  left: 1px;
  position: relative;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: silver;
  z-index: -100;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="parent-text">parent</div>
  <div class="child">child</div>
</div>
```